# Configuration default not found Android studio - Import from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have been using Eclipse and ADT for building my project. It has been working fine. Recently, I tried migrating my project to `Android studio 0.3.7` and I am facing some issues.

My project has a src project, test project, and a library project that successfully get exported from Eclipse.

When I choose the Import Library option, I get the following error.

"Configuration name default not found".

This is my build.gradle for the top level project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-    
projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }
        dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
```

And this is my settings.gradle,

```
include ':tests:MyProjectTest'
include ':mylibrary'
include ':
```

The only modification I have done after the eclipse export is to change the following file:

```
./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

To change

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip
```

I changed the above line to use 1.8 instead of 1.6.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/my_lib_jar.jar')

    compile project(':mylibrary')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

}
```

By the way, your tests must have path 'project_directory/tests/java/package_name/test'

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. I will try this out. One basic question I had was - Whats the point of the Eclipse export if we have to manually edit the generated gradle files?

Comment: Main purpose "Eclipse export" is creating build.gradle file with basic options, but you should manually edit it for your customization options.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a structure like this:

```
Root
- MyProjectTest
    build.gradle
    src
    res
- myLibrary
    build.gradle
    src
    res
settings.gradle
build.gradle
```

In settings.gradle:

```
include ':MyProjectTest', ':myLibrary'
```

In myLibrary/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {

   compileSdkVersion 19
   buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion XX
       targetSdkVersion 19

   }    

   sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']            
                res.srcDirs = ['res']            
            }
        }
    }
```

In Project/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    // Libraries
    compile project(':myLibrary')  
  }
android {

   compileSdkVersion 19
   buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion XX
       targetSdkVersion 19

   }    

   sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']            
                res.srcDirs = ['res']            
            }
        }
    }
```

In your script you are using:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
```

Gradle 1.8 require 0.6.3 version.
You can use

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
```